# Is a VISA card accepted as a payment card on Careers.so.com?

Tags: support, jobs

I live in France, and have only a VISA card. I would like a 3 year subscription.

But I am a little hesitant to do that since I don't see the usual listing of accepted cards.

I know SO is an international website, but I am not used to buying things on American websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, international cards should work!

We just enabled some settings in our payment auth gateway that were blocking some international cards.

If it does *not* work, email careers@stackoverflow.com (the contact email address at the bottom of every careers page).